# OpenShift docker registry can't pull an image from registry-1.docker.io

Tags: docker, redis, openshift, docker-registry, openshift-origin

I'm working with OpenShift version:

```
oc v3.10.0+dd10d17
kubernetes v1.10.0+b81c8f8
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://127.0.0.1:8443
openshift v3.10.0+e3465d0-44
kubernetes v1.10.0+b81c8f8
```

My docker version is:

```
Client:
  Version:           18.06.1-ce
  API version:       1.38
  Go version:        go1.10.3
  Git commit:        e68fc7a
  Built:             Tue Aug 21 17:24:56 2018
  OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
  Experimental:      false

Server:
  Engine:
  Version:          18.06.1-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       e68fc7a
  Built:            Tue Aug 21 17:23:21 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

To start the local OpenShift cluster on my computer I followed steps: https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md#linux

I wanted to deploy a Redis instance and since there is no default Redis template (there are 20 default templates), I loaded it as a JSON template from the URL: https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/db-templates/redis-ephemeral-template.json

When creating the app from this template, the Redis pod cannot start up and signals a following error:

> Failed to pull image "172.30.1.1:5000/openshift/redis@sha256:0cf7163e0589baab918b1d70cd1ed4c711e2430c618c672b9121f1fd35cf562a": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unknown: unable to pull manifest from docker.io/centos/redis-32-centos7:latest: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

When I'm deploying the app by providing a docker image `openshiftroadshow/parksmap-katacoda:1.0.0` - it's being pulled and deployed successfully.

I have logged into the container published at `172.30.1.1:5000` that hosts a docker registry for the OpenShift and there is clearly a problem with resolving `registry-1.docker.io` domain:

```
bash-4.2$ nslookup registry-1.docker.io
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

If I specify `8.8.8.8` DNS, everything is fine:

```
bash-4.2$ nslookup registry-1.docker.io 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 52.22.67.152
....
```

So I looked into `/etc/resolv.conf` file and here is its content:

```
bash-4.2$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 172.30.0.2
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local home
options ndots:5
```

My questions are:

1. Is OpenShift using some internal DNS solution? If so, should I tweak its configuration?
2. Who (and where) is responsible for configuring the content of the `resolv.conf` file?
3. Is there anything wrong with Redis template I'm using?
4. Is it a good practice to add missing templates one-by-one and is it possible to add whole bunch of useful templates that are missing at once?
5. What should I do to make my example work?

I'd be fully appreciate for your help and time!

Comment: That template by default expects the ``redis`` image to exist in the ``openshift`` project. Did you import it into that project, or your own and override the name space it expected to be pulled from?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, how do you know that the template expects `redis` image to exist in the `openshift` project? I did not change the template. Also I wasn't adding or removing any images in the internal docker registry. I tested the same scenario using `minishift` with ODK 3.10 and the image was pulled from `docker.io` registry after not being found in the internal docker registry. Is internal docker registry supposed to be hitting external docker registries (like docker.io) if an image is not found or am I responsible for pushing necessary images to internal docker registry?

Comment: Oh, and I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Is ODK 3.10 supposed to run on it without any issues?

Answer (score 1):

The template at line:

- https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/db-templates/redis-ephemeral-template.json#L196

has:

```
    {
        "description": "The OpenShift Namespace where the ImageStream resides.",
        "displayName": "Namespace",
        "name": "NAMESPACE",
        "value": "openshift"
    },
```

and uses the `NAMESPACE` value at:

- https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/db-templates/redis-ephemeral-template.json#L170

with:

```
                        "from": {
                            "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
                            "name": "redis:${REDIS_VERSION}",
                            "namespace": "${NAMESPACE}"
                        },
```

So the template by default expects the ImageStream for the `redis` image to be in the `openshift` project. This template is itself usually loaded into the `openshift` project through:

- https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/image-streams/image-streams-centos7.json

having been loaded into the `openshift` cluster when created.

So check whether the image stream definitions for the `redis` image are in fact loaded into the `openshift` project using:

```
oc get is/redis -n openshift --as system:admin
```

or:

```
oc login -u system:admin
oc get is/redis -n openshift
```

Which depends on how `oc cluster up` is set up. By default the first may not work.

So ascertain if that image stream for `redis` exists first.

Comment: I checked that the `redis` image stream is defined in the `openshift` project and after invoking `oc describe is/redis -n openshift` I can see that it's linked to `docker.io/centos/redis-32-centos7@sha256:0cf7163e0589baab918b1d70cd1ed4c711e2430c618c672b9121f1fd35cf562a`. The image stream is seen by the deployment config because the deployment is started immediately but since I don't have a `redis` image within my docker image, the openshift tries to pull it from docker.io and that's where I have issues

Comment: This clearly has something to do with my DNS. I changed my `/etc/resolv.conf` to `nameserver 8.8.8.8 + nameserver 8.8.4.4 + search home` and the image is now pulled from docker.io through image stream. Before the change my DNS was set to `nameserver 127.0.1.1 + search home` since I had `dnsmasq` enabled. Do you know what's the typical approach of using DNS from the docker containers managed by OpenShift?